# Does Sunday work require a permit in Italy?

Tags: employment, italy

One of the episodes of Top Gear (Series 18, Episode 1), where they're testing some supercars in Italy, involves them being stopped by the police officers.

The characters feared speeding; turns out, they were stopped for working on a Sunday without a permit!  *(Only in Italy!)*

Is it true that you need some kind of a special permit to work on a Sunday in Italy?

P.S. Prompted by the comment in [Do you need to obey an obstructed traffic sign?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/411/do-you-need-to-obey-an-obstructed-traffic-sign)

Comment: I'm intrigued by this question, also because I'm Italian, and I plan on writing a complete answer, once I find a bit of time. The situation is unclear and we just hear a few words by the Police officer, so it's difficult to say exactly what was going on. Generally speaking, you don't need a permit to work on Sundays. They might have needed a permit either to shoot the video on a public highway on a holiday, or to drive supercars on Sunday (during some Sundays, there are traffic restrictions to reduce pollution).

Answer (score 3):

Art.36, Italy's constitution:

> Workers have the right to a remuneration commensurate to the quantity
> and quality of their work and in any case such as to ensure them and
> their families a free and dignified existence. Maximum daily working
> hours are established by law. Workers have the right to a weekly rest
> day and paid annual holidays. They cannot waive this right.

Italian Civil Code:

> All workers have the right to rest one day a week ( art.36 of the
> Constitution) normally on Sunday (Sect. 2109 Civil Code ).
>
> The 24 hour weekly rest period can be shifted only for special
> activities, dealt with by Act  370/1934 ( article 5). Workers are
> entitled to a compensatory rest.

Civil code and Legislative Decree No. 66 of 2003:

> Core of working time regulation is Legislative Decree No. 66 of 2003,
> implementing the European Directives 93/104/CE and 2000/34/CE, even if
> important principles are still contained in a few norms of the Civil
> Code (dated 1942), namely Article 2107, 2108 and 2019. Under Article 9
> of Legislative Decree No. 66/2003 every worker is entitled, per each
> seven-day period (calculated as an average on a time lapse no longer
> than 14 days) to a minimum uninterrupted rest of 24 hours, as a rule
> on Sunday, plus the 11 hours’ daily rest referred to in the above
> mentioned Art. 7 (in other words, the two periods can’t overlap).
> However, many exceptions are provided in this case too.

In short, while workers are entitled to (at least) a day of rest every 6 days of work, usually on Sundays, there are many exceptions to the rules, as long as at least one day of rest is guaranteed.

However, you don't need a permit to work on a Sunday.

(Note that municipal regulations might prevent local businesses in some cities from *opening to the public* on Sundays, e.g. restaurants, supermarkets, bars..)